# Tkinter return value of function after clicking

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, return, bind

I trying to do simple python game with using Tkinter.
When i click on target point i want process this coords.
I have this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    #setting canvas
    frame = Frame(root, bd=0, relief=SUNKEN)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, width=600, height=600,xscrollcommand=xscroll.set, yscrollcommand=yscroll.set)
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def get_coords(event, TPointsDict,k):
        k+=1
        canvas.create_circle(event.x, event.y, 7, fill="blue", outline="#DDD", width=2)
        return event.x, event.y

    TPointsDict={"target1":(130,220), "target_2":(240, 190)}
    k=0
    canvas.bind("<Button 1>", lambda event, arg=TPointsDict, arg2=k: get_coords(event, arg, arg2))
    root.mainloop()
```

I want return coords from function **get_coords** and then do some operations with them. 
How i can catch return values of **get_coords** function?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to have `get_coords` set either a global or object instance variable. You can't "return" from an event binding because the code calling the function ignores evertything that is returned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bryan! With global variables it's works as i want!